# What is the best way to associate a building with a person?

Tags: contacts

As a neighborhood organization, we use CiviCRM for all of the things you would expect, and it works well. However, we like to collect information about the actual houses in our neighborhood, to track tree pits, security cameras, and other outdoor things that would stay constant, even as people move in and out.

What is the best way to track buildings and associate them with the current residents?

Comment: Thank you for this topic. I am configuring CiviCRM on Joomla and would like to associate boats to owners. I will create a new contact type for boats and a new relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to answer "best way", would need to know what are the tasks you do that use this information and what reporting you need. But as a general answer, one way is to create a new contact type (Admin - Customize - Contact Types), and then add your buildings as contacts. You can create custom fields on those contacts to store camera information etc. Then create a relationship (on the relationship tab on the contact) to the people (or household, depending on whether you're using household records or not, or simply prefer to directly relate to the people). Then when the people leave, you end the relationship(s) and make new ones with the new people.

Comment: I've done exactly what Demerit suggests, relating individuals to 'plots' - where a plot is a subtype of the organisation contact type. This to to track what plot (i.e. piece of cultivated land on an allotment) a person has, and when.  Works perfectly.

Comment: This is a great and clean solution! Thanks Demerit